# Django Admin Interface: how to show different model based on a user's selection?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

I am creating a Poll application using Django. The workflow for the Admin user is as follows:

1. Admin clicks on the **"Add Question"** which shows the Admin a simple page with a dropdown list of 3 types(True/False,Multiple choice, Single choice) of Questions she can create. Basically there will be *3 types of Question Models* for each of the kind.
2. Based on the Admin's selection from the dropdown list, that particular model is shown and the admin can enter values for *different fields of that model.*

That's all! Seems pretty basic, but being a newbie in Django I can't find a solution. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you *have to* use the admin for this? 
I think a series of common forms would serve you better if you want to create a custom workflow which involves processing the data of multiple forms.

You could tie your forms together using Django's [FormWizard](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really behavior you can expect to be baked into django.

Take advantage of what django *does* ship with, the CRUD interfaces, and set up a start page that has a drop down list that redirects to the appropriate model via some JavaScript.

```
<script>
// I'm using jQuery since I can type it as fast as pseudo code...
$(function() {
    $("select").change(function() {
        window.location = $(this).val();
    })
})
</script>

<select>
    <option value="{% url admin:myapp_mymodel1_add %}">Model 1</option>
    <option value="{% url admin:myapp_mymodel2_add %}">Model 2</option>
    <option value="{% url admin:myapp_mymodel3_add %}">Model 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But how do I setup the start page? Do I need to override the admin template? By the way I am using Django-Piston for CRUD.

Comment: You could override the admin index page, set up a new homepage at an arbitrary URL like /admin_home/...